# Why isn't my worksheet deleting in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have stumbled across an interesting problem in Excel. I have a macro which works fine in Excel 2013 (I just tested it prior to posting this and achieved the results I expected) but is failing in Excel 2016.

The macro deletes a few worksheets and saves a copy to wherever the user specifies. I am getting a `Method Delete of Object '_Worksheet' failed` error on my line:

```
Sheets("DPS Scorecard").Delete
```

Now I know the sheet is being referenced correctly because I type `?Sheets("DPS Scorecard").Name` in the immediate window and I get `DPS Scorecard` which is the name I would expect of the sheet.

I tried to use

```
Worksheets("DPS Scorecard").Delete
```

But got the same error.

I thought I should try the codename, which is `Sheet8`, so I even used

```
Sheet8.Delete
```

When I do this, Excel immediately crashes (though I do not receive the error).

I also tried activating another sheet that isn't deleted prior to deleting the necessary sheets, but this produced the same results. I also used `On Error Resume Next` which resulted in the code finishing, of course, but none of the sheets I needed deleted were removed.

The worksheet and workbook are both unprotected.

**Does anyone have any idea why I can delete my worksheet in Excel 2013 but not Excel 2016?**

It's unfortunate because users in my office are being upgraded to 2016 and this is halting a significant business process.

Full subroutine:

```
Sub CreateCPR()

    Dim excelName  As String
    Dim newWB As Workbook, curWB As Workbook

    Set curWB = ThisWorkbook

    'Get Excel save name
    excelName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 1, FindNth(ThisWorkbook.Name, "_", 2)) & "CPR_.xlsm", fileFilter:="Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm)", Title:="Save CPR")

    If excelName <> "False" And excelName <> vbNullString Then

        Application.Calculate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=excelName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False


        'unprotect sheet
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
        ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True


        'Delete sheets & show sheets
        Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
        Sheets("Candidate").Visible = True
        Sheets("DPS Scorecard").Delete
        Sheets("Portfolio Summary").Delete
        Sheets("Detail Data 2017 Q1").Delete
        Sheets("Detail Data 2016 YE").Delete
        Sheets("Detail Data 2015 YE").Delete
        Sheets("Detail Data 2014 YE").Delete
        Sheets("Detail Data 2013 YE").Delete
        Sheets("Instructions").Delete
        Sheets("Slicer Parameters").Delete

        Sheets("Summary").Select
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("DPS - Candidate").Unprotect Password:="password"
        Sheets("DPS - Seller").Unprotect Password:="password"
        Sheets("Summary").Activate

        'Order the tabs
        Sheets("Summary").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
        Sheets("DPS - Candidate").Move After:=Sheets("Summary")
        Sheets("Candidate").Move After:=Sheets("DPS - Candidate")
        Sheets("DPS - Seller").Move After:=Sheets("Candidate")

        Sheets("Summary").Activate

        On Error GoTo 0

        ThisWorkbook.Save

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Current workaround:

I just use `Sheets.Cells.Clear` and set the sheets to `xlVeryHidden` for the sheets I am trying to delete. That will at least get me by for the time being until I can figure out why `Delete` isn't working.

Comment: Did you try to record a macro and check what is the auto-generated code for deleting a worksheet? Are you able to delete this worksheet manually?

Comment: Could it be that this sheet or Workbook are protected ?

Comment: Doesn't appear that either the sheet or workbook is protected, though I hadn't checked it prior. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Please include a full MCVE of your VBA code so we can determine what the issue is.

Comment: I added the full subroutine. `ActiveSheet` will be the `DPS Scorecard` sheet because the user clicks a button on that sheet to start the subroutine, though I could change that to be a more strict qualifier.

Comment: Also when I get the error and the code breaks, Excel inevitably crashes. I clicked to stop the macro and it's done.

Comment: If it was not from this line, would this sub fail on the next line anyway ? The one deleting "Portfolio Summary" ?

Comment: Oh wait, is the code running from a Module or from this very same sheet ?

Comment: Code runs from a module. I've implemented the workaround described and it's been quiet today, but I still haven't figured out the root cause. And yes it fails at deleting every sheet.